# Compare two different arrays in Actionscript 3 using For Loop within a For Loop

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop

basically I need a loop within a loop to compare two different arrays in my actionscript3 lottery game.
I have attempted the loop but I cannot seem to get it to work ...

```
check_win.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f_check_win);
function f_check_win(event:Event):void{ 
for(index = 0; index < matches[index]; index++ ){
trace(index);
    for(index2 = 0; index2 < input_array.length; index2++){
        if (match[index2] == input_array[index2]){
            choose_change = choose_change+1;
        }
    }
}
```

So basically within this code check_win is a button. Once the button is clicked it runs the loop. It is meant to take an instance of matches which contains 6 properties and loop until index is greater than matches. According to my output this is happening but the second loop doesn't appear to do anything. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you've provided, it looks like your inner loop should look more like this:

```
for(index2 = 0; index2 < input_array.length; index2++){
    if (matches[index] == input_array[index2]){
        choose_change = choose_change+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this seemed to have worked for now. I will switch out matches (which at the moment contains 1-6) for my random number class. If i have any issues I will comment back.